# Vim csupport; Change c compiler to clang

Tags: c, vim, clang

We required to use the *CLANG* compiler with the *C99* standard and AddressSanitizer (ASAN) turned on, however I cannot figure out how to change these settings using the *csupport* plugin.

I have read the relevant sections of the help file but I'm still lost, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the global variable `g:C_CCompiler` to clang and set the flags using `g:C_CFlags`

More information can be found [here](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-c/csupport.html#csupport-custom-glob-vars)